# image is not showing in edit blade

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

hi m trying to edit data but on edit.blade.php all data isn't showing including image, only category_name value is showing , how to resolve it?,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,all data isn't showing including image, only category_name value is showing

edit.blade.php:

```
    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('admin.category.update', $categories->id) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    @csrf
                    @method('PATCH')
                    <strong class="text-muted d-block mb-2">Category Name</strong>
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                      <div class="input-group input-group-seamless">
                        <input type="text" name="category_name" class="form-control @error('category_name') is-invalid @enderror" value="{{ $categories->category_name }}" id="">
                      </div>
                      @error('category_name')
                        <div class="small text-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
                      @enderror
                    </div>
                    <strong class="text-muted d-block mb-2">Description</strong>
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                      <div class="input-group input-group-seamless">
                        <textarea name="category_description" class="form-control @error('category_description') is-invalid @enderror" value="{{ $categories->category_description }}"></textarea>
                      </div>
                      @error('category_description')
                        <div class="small text-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
                      @enderror
                    </div>
                    <strong class="text-muted d-block mb-2">Slug</strong>
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                      <div class="input-group input-group-seamless">
                        <input type="text" name="category_slug" class="form-control @error('category_slug') is-invalid @enderror" value="{{ $categories->category_slug }}"> </div>
                        @error('category_slug')
                          <div class="small text-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
                        @enderror
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                      <div class="input-group input-group-seamless">
                         <input type="file" name="category_image" class="form-control mb-2 btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary mr-1 @error('category_image') is-invalid @enderror" value="{{ $categories->category_image }}">
                      </div>
                         @error('category_image')
                          <div class="small text-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
                        @enderror
                        <img src="{{ URL::to('/') }}/images/{{ $categories->category_image }}" class="img-thumbnail" width="100" />
                         <input type="hidden" name="hidden_image" value="{{ $categories->category_image }}" />
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="mb-2 btn btn-primary mr-2">Edit Category</button>
                  </form>
```

controller:

```
  public function edit(Category $category)
  {
    $categories = Category::findOrFail($category->id);
    return view('admin.category.edit', compact('categories'));
  }
```

Comment: Can you print_r($categories) on edit function? is categories_image appears in array? also make sure in your model not to be in hidden array.

Comment: undefined variable categories then i change it to category and output is:   ay ( [0] => category_name [1] => category_description [2] => category_slug [3] => category_image ) [connection:protected] => mysql [table:protected] => categories [primaryKey:protected] => id [keyType:protected] => int [incrementing] => 1 [with:protected] => Array ( ) [withCount:protected] => Array ( ) [perPage:protected] => 15 [exists] => 1 [wasRecentlyCreated] => [attributes:protected] => Array ( [id] => 27 [category_name] => newone cat [category_descricreated_at] => 2019-07-28 17:25:21 [updated_atnges:protected] =>

Comment: can you make sure this is the correct source of your image? kindly inspect it and check if  it shows the image link correctly.

Comment: yes in inspect real image is showing

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a resource controller then your edit function should look like this:

```
 public function edit(Category $category)
 {
     return view('admin.category.edit', compact('category'));
 }
```

You're running the same query twice.
Also make sure you're using a resource route:

```
 Route::resource('category', 'CategoryController');
```

See [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers#resource-controllers)